# Make header available on all components except on login

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Supposed I am importing a header component on **layouts/default.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-container class="mt-5">
      <b-row>
        <b-col md="6" class="mb-3">
          <Header />
        </b-col>
        <b-col md="6">
          <nuxt />
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
    <Header/>
    <nuxt/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "@/components/Header.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Header
  }
};
</script>

<style>
...
</style>
```

and that header will be render on all components.

My question is how can I make the header available on all components except on my `Login.vue`?

Any idea on where can I start to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by reading the documentation on https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views/ `layouts section`. I created another layout file on layouts folder login.vue and use it on my main login.vue

```
export default {
  layout: 'login' // coming from layouts folder
  // page component definitions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current route path is '$route.path',so use 'v-show' to judge.